# Performance on Web Service return Collection

Tags: .net, performance, web-services

I'm wondering what would have better performance for a .net webservice. I have to return a large collection of "Order" objects in a webservice. Would it perform better to have one method return just a list of order ids and then call another method to get the individual order objects from an order id, or just return all order objects with one call?

EDIT:

It is .asmx for .net 3.5 and it's a collection of order objects placed on an e-commerce store. So, it'll be a class with info on the order and this object will have associations with other objects like shipments, items, notes...etc.

Comment: WCF or ASMX service? Which binding? Which version of .NET? Collection of what? You may need to provide a little detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell which is best for your scenario since you don't describe the usage scenario of the service.

If it's likely that you will use the full details of many orders, return them all or maybe a paged result (say the first 20 orders or so) and allow the caller to get the next 20 and so on. It depends on how large the data set is. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804/returning-large-results-via-a-webservice) for more thoughts about providing large datasets from web services.

If the caller of the service is more likely to just use one result at a time it's unnecessary to get the entire list at once.